# Apply XSL translate across the entire XML

Tags: xml, xslt

So the below XSL coverts any hyphens to blank spaces to `Foo` in our XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Foo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate( ., '-', ' ')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The above XSLT works great but only applies to `Foo`. Is there a way to have the translate apply to all elements without setting it up individually for each element (while keeping the original XML structure intact)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do string processing the right approach is to use `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="translate(., '-', ' ')"/></xsl:template>`, that processes all text nodes.

While `match="*"` would allow you to match all elements, your current template would then copy the root element and translate and output its string value, but not process any child elements further. So using `match="text()"` is more appropriate, of course then without `xsl:copy`.

Of course, for the whole approach to work, you need to use the identity transformation template

`<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: Thanks. I just tried what you provided and it seemed to have the same result as my unsuccessful attempts. It strips away all the <Tags> and just lists of the tag values. This is what I tried:

Comment: This is a very complex XML with a lot of parent child relationships.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain in more detail how to use my suggestion.

Comment: You were assuming I was smarter than I am. hahahaha. Thank you for updating the answer. That worked perfectly!